# How to know when Bluetooth disconnects on Android 1.5?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I got code which works perfectly for Android 1.6 and higher with BT.  The issue I'm having is that in Android 1.5 I don't have a way to know when BT is disconnecting.

The main issue is that in Android 1.5 I get the ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY and I mute audio.  I unmute at headset unplug or BT disconnect.  In the case of Android 1.5 I can't unmute because I never got the BT disconnect...

Any ideas how I can overcome this issue with BT?

Comment: I don't think there is BT support for Android 1.5. The apis came in with 1.6

Comment: Advantej is right. No BT in android 1.5. Sorry

Comment: I do understand that BT is not supported by Android 1.5. I thought maybe somehow there would be a hidden Intent or such I could capture.  what bothers me a little is that ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY is sent after BT disconnection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no particular way to resolve this issue.